# Por que não é possível capturar exceções disparadas por async void?

Tags: c#, exceção, assincronismo, task, async-await

Por que não é possível capturar exceções disparadas por métodos assíncronos que não retornam `Task`?

```
public async void calcularPrecos()
{
    var tabelaPreco = await getTabelaPreco();
    /* Blá, blá, blá... */
}

public void iniciarCalculos()
{
    try
    {
        calcularPrecos();
        /* Blá, blá, blá... */
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        /* A exceção é disparada mas não é capturada neste ponto. =( */
    }
}
```

O método `getTabelaPreco()` exige conexão com a internet, caso contrário, ele dispara uma exceção do tipo `WebException`, porém não consigo capturar tal exceção no `try-catch` dentro de `iniciarCalculos()`.

Comment: Talvez se criar um [mcve] fique mais fácil identificar o problema.

Comment: Caro @bigown, este é um exemplo real, achei que as linhas consequentes não adicionariam na resolução do problema.

Comment: Se fosse real daria para compilá-lo. Continuo com minha sugestão para fazer da forma indicada lá. E não é para colocar todo o código, só o mínimo para verificar a condição do erro, no momento não dá para ter certeza do que esse código faz e porque a exceção não é capturada, pode ser até porque ela não foi lançada.

Comment: Amigo, seu método `iniciarCalculos` não está assíncrono, isso não vai funcionar direito (provável também que este seja o problema). Use as palavras reservadas `async` e `await` nesse método assim como você fez no `calcularPrecos`.

Comment: Link relacionado https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13897

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é capturada porque o método `calcularPrecos()` retorna nada(void).

Para que a excepção seja propagada é necessário que ele retorne `Task` ou `Task<T>`.

Quando uma excepção é lançada a partir de uma tarefa assíncrona que retorne `Task` ou `Task <T>`, ela é capturada e colocada no objecto `Task` retornado.

No caso de métodos que retornam `void` não há nenhum objecto `Task`, portanto, quaisquer excepções lançadas não poderão ser capturadas(a não ser observando o [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Note que a excepção só é lançada quando a tarefa é executada.
O try/catch só captará a excepção nesse altura.

No seu exemplo<sup>(1)</sup>, mesmo que o método `calcularPrecos()` retornasse uma `Task`, o bloco `try/catch` não capturaria a excepção porque, quando ela ocorrer, a execução já terá saído desse bloco.

Assim, para chamar o método terá de usar `await calcularPrecos();` ou `calcularPrecos().Wait();`

Veja o que diz a documentação sobre [Async Return Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674893.aspx).

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> Ver o [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148940/por-que-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-poss%c3%advel-capturar-exce%c3%a7%c3%b5es-disparadas-por-m%c3%a9todos-ass%c3%adncronos/148966#comment307574_148966) do Gabriel Katakura.</sub>

Comment: Não basta somente colocar `Task` em `calcularPrecos`, na chamada do método `calcularPrecos` também é necessário efetuar um `Wait()` caso o método que esteja efetuando a chamada (desculpa o termo estranho) seja um método síncrono. Fica aqui a solução: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LDQpuG

Comment: @GabrielKatakura Obrigada pela chamada de atenção, editei a resposta.