# Quando não retornar Task em métodos async?

Tags: c#, .net, async, assincronismo, task

Normalmente, em algumas tarefas demoradas, utilizo métodos assíncronos:

```
public async Task myLongRunningOperation(int i) { ... }
```

Porém, em que situações eu não necessariamente preciso retornar uma `Task`?

```
public async void myLongRunningOperation(int i) { ... }
```

Qual é a diferença e o impacto causado na declaração dos dois métodos acima?

Comment: Relacionado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148940/2541

Comment: Link relacionado https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13897

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Todo método `async` deve sim retornar um `Task` - independente se irá ou não aguardar pelo seu fim.

Um método `async` - além da obviedade de ser um método assíncrono - quer dizer que será criada uma nova `Thread` para executar sua ação. E para que vc tenha o controle do ciclo de vida dessa tarefa, seu método retorna um tipo `Task` para que assim vc possa saber quando essa tarefa terminou, se quiser terminar com a sua execução ou mesmo para saber o que ela retornou.

O problema de se criar um método `async void` é que não existe esse controle, e a execução dessa tarefa pose ser terminada antes do fim de sua execução. Veja o exemplo:

```
public async Task EnviarEmailAsync()
{
    // ação para envio do email
    // normalmente é demorado, leva mais que 100ms por exemplo.
    return;
}
```

Para consumir, fazemos:

```
await EnviarEmailAsync();
return;
```

Isso vai garantir que seu código irá aguardar o envio do email antes de retornar.

Usando agora um exemplo sem retornar uma `Task`:

```
public async void EnviarEmailAsync()
{
    // ação para envio do email
    // normalmente é demorado, leva mais que 100ms por exemplo.
    return;
}
```

Para consumir, fazemos:

```
EnviarEmailAsync();
return;
```

Nesse caso, ao retornar, a `Task` - que existe, mas apenas não foi retornar, e não há referencias para ela - irá ser cancelada.

Voce pode testar isso [neste exemplo no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8NViR1).

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inicio de envio de emails.");
            await EnviarEmailAsync();
            EnviarEmail();      

            Console.WriteLine("Fim de execução.");
        }).Wait();
    }

    public static async Task EnviarEmailAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(500)); // simula envio de email, que dure 500ms       
        Console.WriteLine("Email A enviado.");
    }

    public static async void EnviarEmail()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(500)); // simula envio de email, que dure 500ms       
        Console.WriteLine("Email B enviado.");
    }
}
```

O resultado será:

```
> Inicio de envio de emails.
> Email A enviado.
> Fim de execução.
```

Não terá o retorno do método `async void`, pois ele teve seu cancelamento forçado pelo fim do seu "invocador" - o método `Main()`.

Answer (score 8):

Eu não sei dar muitos detalhes sem pesquisar mais, mas todo mundo considera um erro existir o retorno `void` em um método `async`. Há uma maneira diferente para lidar com exceções que causa problemas na aplicação, então a resposta pragmática para a pergunta título é **nunca**.

Se quiser insistir nisso saiba que a aplicação não esperará o termino para continuar dali e em poucos casos isto é interessante.

Veja [blog sobre isto](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/). Tem [outro artigo](https://www.filipekberg.se/2012/09/20/avoid-shooting-yourself-in-the-foot-with-tasks-and-async/). E o [recente artigo do Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170721-00/?p=96665&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Em complemento às respostas:

Métodos assíncronos que não retornam `Task` ou uma `Task<T>` são perigosos pelo seu controle "estranho" de exceções em sua execução. Você não tem como monitorar a vida desse método, o fim dele. É um *fire and forget*, atirar e esquecer.

Essas exceções que são engolidas em métodos `async void` são disparadas e podem ser vistas criando um *handler* para algum desses eventos que capturam todas as exceções não tratadas da aplicação como o `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` e o `AppDomain.UnhandledException`.

Como dito nas respostas acima, e confirmando com uma boa fonte: um autor da MSDN Magazine [confirma](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) que devemos **SEMPRE** retornar `Task` ou `Task<T>` em métodos assíncronos, mesmo que não precisemos esperar pela execução do mesmo.

**A única exceção** para usar `async void` são *handlers* de eventos, como o clique de um botão. Mas ainda sim, todo cuidado é preciso, num caso em que você utilize os parâmetros do handler do evento, você deveria evitar o `async void`, já que o fluxo de execução não espera pelo seu término.

```
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { ... }
```

Algumas discussões interessantes sobre o assunto:

- [SOen: async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void)
- [GitHub Roslyn Repo: Proposal: Deprecate async void](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13897)
- [theburningmonk.com: beware of async void in your code](http://theburningmonk.com/2012/10/c-beware-of-async-void-in-your-code/)