# Existe uma maneira segura de não se esperar por um processo?

Tags: c#, .net, assincronismo

Existe uma maneira segura de não se esperar por um processo no .NET?

```
async Task DoFoo()
{
    // ...
    GravarLog();
    // ...
}

void GravarLog()
{
    // ...
}
```

No código acima, o meu processo inteiro irá esperar pela finalização do método `GravarLog()`, o que para mim não é necessário, e esse método poderia ser executado em *background*, sem que eu tenha que esperar por ele para executar o resto do meu código. (gravação de log foi somente um exemplo que usei para contextualizar)

Uma alternativa, porém muito volátil, seria o `async void` como um "*fire and forget*" (ou "*fire and crash*"):

```
async Task DoFoo()
{
    // ...
    GravarLog();
    // ...
}

async void GravarLog()
{
    // ...
}
```

Existem muitos artigos e opiniões dizendo para evitar a todo custo utilizar `async void`, pois o controle de exceções é diferente do padrão do .NET:

- [haacked.com: Avoid async void methods](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/)
- [MSDN: Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)
- [SOpt: Quando não retornar Task em método assíncronos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219461/41056)

Como não precisar "esperar" pela finalização de um método de maneira segura?

Comment: Não vejo problema em esperar gravar um log, porque (até hoje o que eu vi) a gravação de logs é algo bem rápido. Mas se for um processo pesado, já pensou em delegar essa responsabilidade para um Task Scheduler?

Comment: Nunca fiz o tratamento desses casos manualmente (não precisei), sempre usei ferramentas para isto, então não posso explicar como fazer o processo manual de controle disto. Mas uma ferramenta que trata muito bem disso é o Hangfire.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura foi a maneira que achei para contextualizar: logs, telemetria =P. Vou dar uma olhada nesse Hangfire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rodei em segundo plano criando uma nova *thread*.

```
async Task DoFoo()
{
    // ...
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        GravarLog();
    }).Start();
    // ...
}

void GravarLog()
{
    // operação síncrona
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa que sempre usava é chamar o `TaskFactory`. Eu nunca ouvi mal dizeres sobre o mesmo, mas posso estar errado. Nunca tive problemas com o mesmo:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
...
TaskFactory runner = new TaskFactory();
Action task = () => GravarLog();
runner.StartNew(task);
```

Assim, ela irá ser chamada em segundo plano, sem com que precise usar o `async`.

Comment: seria `runner.StartNew(task);` ?

Comment: Erro meu. Esqueci de substituir isso, acabei de corrigir.