# Erro ao tentar conexão assíncrona

Tags: c#, assincronismo, tcp, tcpclient

Estou tentando fazer dessa forma para não travar o aplicativo durante a espera pelo servidor aceitar a conexão. Vi que da pra fazer com `async` e o `await`.
Mas ao tentar usa-los para esperar a conexão sem travar, o programa retorna infinitamente um `Exception`:

> Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in MessengerTcpIp.exe

E fica todo travado. Ele da esse problema na hora de esperar o servidor responder.

Código:

```
private async void ConnectServer()
        {
            try
            {
                server = IPAddress.Parse(serverAddr.Text);
                port = 12303;
                user = new TcpClient();
                connBtn.Text = "Aguardando conexão";
                await user.ConnectAsync(server, port);
                strWriter = new StreamWriter(user.GetStream());
                strReader = new StreamReader(user.GetStream());
                strWriter.AutoFlush = true;
                StrWriter.WriteLine(email.Text);
                StrWriter.WriteLine(password.Text);
                var SvResponse = await strReader.ReadLineAsync();
                if(SvResponse == "ok")
                {
                    userInfo.AppendText("Conectado com sucesso.");
                    connBtn.Text = "Conectado";
                } 
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.show("Falha ao se conectar.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception:" + err.Message, "Erro de conexão.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                connBtn.Text = "Conectar";
            }

        }
```

Botão que chama:

```
private void Conectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConnectServer();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Voce criou um metodo assincrono, mas não está esperando ele terminar a execução.

Troque o codigo pelo seguinte:

```
private void Conectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(ConnectServer()).Wait();
}
```

E veja essa minha resposta sobre [chamada assincronas com async e await](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219433/quando-n%C3%A3o-retornar-task-em-m%C3%A9todos-async/219469#219469). Tem um exemplo bem legal mostrando como funciona e o que ocorre quando mal empregado.

Comment: Thiago, desculpe eu não entendi muito bem, quando eu tentei dessa maneira obtive o erro: `Cannot convert from void to System.Action`.

Comment: Pq vc não deve criar metodos assincronos que não possuem retorno. Todo metodo assincrono deve retornar Task - se não retornar valor algum - ou Task<T> se retornar algum valor. Vide a resposta que linkei sobre chamadas assincronas, explica direitinho isso lá.

Comment: Sim, entendi agora, porém com o `Task.Run(() => ConnectServer()).Wait();` não dá certo, porque quando clica em conectar todo o fluxo trava e espera a conexão finalizar... eu quero que não trave.